# laravel difference between crypt::encrypt and crypt::encryptString

Tags: laravel, crypt

I am still new on laravel, and just use laravel package name `Crypt`

but I found some that there are

```php
Crypt::encrypt
```

and

```php
Crypt::encryptString
```

what is the difference between them?

Comment: `Crypt::encrypt` : "Encrypted values are passed through serialize during encryption, which allows for encryption of objects and arrays."  More info in the doc https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/encryption

Comment: Consider accepting my answer as correct if it helped you. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can always refer to source code to know.

See [Line 122 of Encrypter.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/0facb7b478f98c8b73617153ae72d1a4947eadd3/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php#L122):

```
    return $this->encrypt($value, false);
```

Behind the scenes the `encryptString` calls the `encrypt()` method with `false` as second parameter, meaning that it won't serialize the value you give.

There's no difference in the behavior, but it will encrypt faster and the result will be slightly smaller because it won't contain string serialization.

Comment: Unless you use it in on a lot of data, I believe the main advantage is that `encryptString` allow a non-PHP application to decrypt the value since serialize is PHP specific